# Swift / Backendless / Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use the backendless API for registering a user. I did everything step by step needed to correctly import the framework.

The AppDelegate.swift is accepting the framework.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    backendless.initApp(APP_ID, secret:SECRET_KEY, version:VERSION_NUM)
//    DebLog.isActive = true
    backendless.hostURL = "https://api.backendless.com"
    backendless.initApp(APP_ID, secret: SECRET_KEY, version: VERSION_NUM)
    return true
    }
```

But as soon as I use backendless in my ViewController, I receive an error.

```
@IBAction func rememberMe(sender: AnyObject) {
    backendless.userService.stayLoggedIn = sender.on
}
```

**Use of unresolved identifier 'backendless'**

I started the project and the import 3-4 times and did it exactly like explained in the documentation, but I always receive this error.
I appreciate every help.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial you used?

Comment: https://backendless.com/documentation/users/ios/users_requirements.htm

Comment: Configure project for iOS development

Comment: Did you forget backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance() in your viewcontroller viewdidload? and backendless as a global in the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look towards the top of the `AppDelegate.swift` file you will see

```
var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()
```

This sets the `backendless` instance variable to the shared instance of the Backendless framework, but this instance variable is local to the AppDelegate instance.  You need this same line in your `ViewController.swift` otherwise the compiler doesn't know what `backendless` is - it is an unresolved identifier

Comment: well. that helped. thank you. don't know, why they don't do that in the example codes inside the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new project in Xcode as you normally would, then close the project.
2. Open a Terminal window, and change the current directory to be the project's directory.
3. Run the following command in the Terminal window, which will create a file with the name Podfile.

   pod init
4. Open the created Podfile using a text editor and add the following text inside of the target block:

   pod 'Backendless', '4.0b2'
5. Save Podfile, return to the Terminal window and run the following command:

   $ pod install

**Don't forgot pod update**
    $ pod update

6. Once the pod is downloaded, Xcode project workspace file will be created. This should be the file you use to open the project in Xcode.
7. If you develop with Swift, you will need to add a Swift bridging header. To do that, click the root node in the Project Structure and select the Build Settings section. Locate the Swift Compiler - General section. Enter the following value into the Objective-C Bridging Header field:

   **Pods/Backendless/SDK/ios/backendless/include/Backendless-Bridging-Header.h**
8. Open .xcworkspace file to launch your project, and build it.

For more detail Please open below link
https://backendless.com/docs/ios/doc.html#setup